# How to define a global visibly operator

Tags: c++, operator-keyword, friend

I wanted to use binary_search on my class and so I defined a operator<. It works when everything is in main file, but when I write the class in another file I got linker error.

The simplest example that shows the problem is
B.h:

```
class B
{
public:
~B(void);
string b;
int v;
B(int val, string bb);
friend bool operator< (const B &lhs, const B &rhs);
 };

 bool operator< (const B &lhs, const B &rhs){
    return lhs.v < rhs.v;
};
```

B.cpp just defines the constructor.
Main is sth like this:

```
#include "B.h"
int main( int argc, const char* argv[] )
{

vector<B> vec;
B a1(2, "gg");
B a2(4, "gdhd");
    vec.push_back(a2);
    vec.push_back(a1);
bool pos = binary_search(vec.begin(),vec.end(), B(2, "ghd"));
}
```

The error LNK2005: "bool __cdecl operator<(class B const &,class B const &)" (??M@YA_NABVB@@0@Z) already defined in Main.obj
: fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found

How to fix it ?

Comment: Have you tried separating and respectively putting the *function declaration* and the *function definition* into `.h` and `.cpp` files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because the operator is improperly defined in the header file. You need to make it `inline` (or `static`).

If it's not `inline` or `static`, the function will be defined in each source file you include the header file in, leading to multiple definition errors.

Comment: It works in this simple example but when I put this idea to whole project I got error like this :  error C2678: binary '<' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const B(or there is no acceptable conversion)
could be 'built-in C++ operator<B*, B*)' or       'bool operator <(const B&,const B&)' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
while trying to match the argument list '(const B, B *)'
see reference to function template instantiation 'bool std::binary_search. Any ideas for it? The operator is the same as in the example so it does not change anything

Comment: @SebastianCygert I can't see your whole error message properly in the comment, but it seems that one argument is a pointer. Your operator does not handle pointers.

Answer (score 2):

You're defining the operator function in a header file, which means every .cpp file which includes it gets its own copy. You have two possible solutions:

1. Mark the function `inline`.
2. Move the function into a .cpp file

Answer (score 0):

Functions not declared `inline` must be  defined in at most one translation unit. By having `B.cpp` and the file copntaining `main()` include the `B.h`header, you get two definitions. Conversely, if you declare a function `inline`, the definition needs to be included in each translation unit where it is used, so having the definition in the header is the right thing to do.

So, if you want the implementation of the operator to stay in the header, you need to use an `inline` qualifier on its definition - or define the operator directly inside the definition of `class B`, where you declare it a friend. The latter will make it implicitly inline.

Otherwise you need to move the definition of the operator to the `B.cpp` file.